# Add leading zeros to a varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that is `varchar(8)`, holding date values that I converted from `float` to `varchar`.

Some records have eight characters, and some have seven.  I would like to make them all the same length by adding a leading zero to the ones that have 7.

- 8 char example: 12162003
- 7 char example: 5072004 (needs a leading zero)

The query:

```
select birthdate_new from table_name
```

Comment: Will you ever have 6? Would Jan 1 be 112015?

Comment: Add a date column to your table and store birth dates in that column.

Comment: Agree with Dan. A date column is best. These avoid the problem: is 1112014 1/11/14 or 11/1/14.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A function that will work for more situations would be REPLICATE.  It concatenates a value X amount of times to a string.

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(birthdate_new)) + birthdate_new AS 8_len_birthdate
```

This will take the length of your birthdate, subtract it from 8, then put that many leading 0's on the front to make it 8 chars.

Comment: please add information about [`lpad`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp) in yout answer

Answer (score 14):

You can use `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000000' + birthdate_new, 8) AS birthdate_new
FROM table_name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403471)**</kbd>

If you want to `UPDATE` field use:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET birthdate_new = RIGHT('00000000' + birthdate_new, 8)
WHERE LEN(birthdate_new) < 8;
```

Answer (score 2):

As its always 7/8 you could:

```
select right('0' + fld, 8)
```

or

```
select case when len(fld) = 7 then '0' else '' end + fld
```