# Parse nvarchar column and add leading 0s

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column that is an `nvarchar`. I would like to update that column for any rows that currently have a value and only if their value is less than 1,000.

Pseudo code:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
IF (PARSE(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN) < 1000)
    SET TABLE_NAME.COLUMN = ADD-LEADING-ZEROS(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN)
ELSE
    do nothing
```

So basically, if the column contains the value `"123"` I would like to update it to be `"0123"`. If it's `"12"` I would like to update it to be `"0012"`, etc.

I'm aware of how to [pad leading 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900) but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into an update statement since I am still pretty new to sql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16760967/656243

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093816/add-leading-zeros-to-a-varchar-field

Comment: This is called padding. Googling 'pad t-sql' shows a ton of results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Cool, thanks. And as I mentioned in my post, I was aware of the different ways to accomplish "padding" 0s but I wasn't sure how to incorporate it into an update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEN` for this:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Column = RIGHT('0000'+Column,4)
WHERE LEN(Column) < 4
;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'll accept the answer once the time expires and SO allows me to.